# Could not find YouTube addon for OpenElec

Tags: kodi, openelec

I have installed OpenElec XBMC on my Raspberry Pi.  I checked the IP address and also the internet activity (I could see weather info and the news feed). Here's what I did to install the YouTube addon:

1. Selected Video
2. Selected Addon
3. Get Addon (and browsing)
4. Selected XBMC addon (YouTube was not there)
5. Searched for "YouTube", "youtube", and "you tube" with no luck.

Am I missing anything here?

Comment: What version of OpenElec are you running?

Comment: @Hurgh its frodo

Comment: It [looks like it was a bug](http://forum.xbmc.org/showthread.php?tid=177503&pid=1546054#pid1546054).  Make sure your system is fully updated and try again maybe?

Comment: works fine now.. may be mirror issue for few days!

Comment: If you get any further errors with YouTube, the trick is to sign into YouTube on the Pi, and do that a second time.

Answer (score 1):

Did you install openeelec from NOOBS or just normal install? If you installed it from NOOBS, YouTube should already be installed, if not, try re-downloading the official addon repository.